# get attachment title based on attachment id

Tags: images, title

I'm getting an image through `getMeta`. It returns me the id of the attachment. Now I want to get the titel, alternative text, description and so on.

For the alternative text this works very well:

```
get_post_meta($logo, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
```

Now I want to get the title. I found out I can do that with `$attachment->post_title`, but here I only have the id. How do I get the title for an attachment id?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you have the attachment id, you can use `get_the_title()`

```
$attachment_title = get_the_title($attach_id)
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title